# Trying to make a basic parallax website with css

Tags: html, css

So here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
   <div class="topbar"></div>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="pic1"></div>
  <header class="headings">
    <h1 align="center">Header</h1>
    <h3 align="center">smaller header</h3>
  </header>
  <form class="form">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" autofocus/></br>
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password"></br>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
  </form>
  <div class="bottombar">
    <h1 align="center"><ins>About Us</ins></h1>
    <p>blah blah blah</br>blah blah blah</br>blah blah blah</br></p>
  </div>
   <div class="pic2"><p>Text 1</p></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and here's my CSS for the background images

```
.pic1{
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url("fog.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 0vw, 0vh;
  padding-top: 50vh;
  padding-bottom: 50vh;

}
.pic2{
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url("butterfly.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  top: 115vh;
  padding-top: 45vh;
  padding-bottom: 35vh;

}
```

[image]

[image]

Hopefully you can see, but thebackground pics dont take up the whole screen, and there's a thin white border around them on the sides. The top bar and About Us bar span the whole page from the left to the right, but not the background pics.

Comment: First your `.topbar` should not be in the `<head>` tag move it into the body.  Then try to give the body and html 0 padding and margin.  `html, body{ padding: 0; margin: 0;}`

Comment: Nothing changed even after giving html and the body 0 padding

Comment: Add the margin 0 also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are on track. Just a few adjustments to make the parallax feel just right.

- You need to set width and height properties of the parallax boxes instead of padding.
- Also set background-size to cover (so the image actually fills the screen/container)
- Center the background image (optional)

Take a look at this https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-surf-df0u5?file=/styles.css (relevant code displayed below)

```css
.pic1 {
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1149362/pexels-photo-1149362.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;

  /* take note of these changes */
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.pic2 {
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1793525/pexels-photo-1793525.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;

  /* take note of these changes */
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```